# get datetime from a sql database

Tags: php

Im trying to get the datetime to get a form of date.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("******","******","*****");
if($con) {
    $db = mysql_select_db("*****");
    if($db) {
        $sql = "SELECT title, longstory, author, published FROM cms_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<ul class='menu-list' id='news-list'>";
                echo "<li><a href='{url}/news/".$row['id']."'>".$row['title']."<span>".$row['published']."</span></a> </li>";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else
            echo "";
    } else
        echo "";
} else
    echo "";
?>
```

http://prntscr.com/eedv2w
That inside the red is the code. But i wants it like that under.

Comment: look at `strtotime();`

Comment: Please post the cms_news table description, is it datetime or timestamp?

Comment: Where i put that?

Comment: and stop using `mysql_*` functions they are depreciated use mysqli or pdo prepared statements

Comment: the time is in the table published in cms_news

Comment: What is the `333..`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use as below:

Instead of `$row['published']` You can use `date('l d. F Y', strtotime($row['published']))`

If you store direct strtotime into the database then you need to replace with `date('l d. F Y', $row['published'])`

Comment: the website crashed

Comment: Simply replace ```$row['published']``` in php with ```date('l d. F Y', strtotime($row['published']))```

Comment: works, but not select the time. So its says "Thursday 01. January 1970"

Comment: Okay, Can you please write exact format which you want. :)

Comment: The format it right, but the date is wrong. its gonna say "Wednesday 22. February 2017"

Comment: If you check echo date('l d. F Y', strtotime('2017-02-22')); then you will find exact output what you want. May be the `$row['published']` will be problematic.

Comment: But my value on the strotime is 1487771270, then it not works.

Comment: Ah okay, Now i understood, Please check updated answer.

Comment: Try ```date('l d. F Y', $row['published'])```, Surely it will work for you :)